# Iterate through a list to use then use SearchCursor to populate new list

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a featureclass of buildings.  Each one has a unique number ("BO_UNIQ").  I create a list of these unique numbers (1251 elements).  I then want to iterate though this list and get facility names from another table by building number. There are multiple facilities for each building number.  Eventually I will add the elements of the facility list to field(s) in the buildings featureclass.

As it is now the script will iterate one time with the da.SearchCursor

What am I missing?

```
# Import modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment
env.workspace = r"PATH\EAD Facility Names\EAD_NAMES.gdb"
env.overwriteOutput = True


# set variables
buildList = []
fieldList = ["FACIL1", "FACIL2", "FACIL3", "FACIL4", "FACIL5", "FACIL6", "FACIL7", "FACIL8"]
eadBuild = "EAD_BUILDINGS"
eadTable = "tblEADFacilities"

# populate buildList with building numbers
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(eadBuild, ["BO_UNIQ"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        buildList.append(row[0])
        print(row)

print(buildList)
print(len(buildList))

# Iterate through list of BO#s
for build in buildList:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(eadTable, ["Name"], "BO =" + str(build)) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            facList = []
            facList.append(row)
            print(row)
    print(build)  # Will iterate and print all elements of the buildList and not run the SearchCursor branch.
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply "modern" Python ( [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [Python List Comprehensions: Explained Visually](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)) ?

```
faclist = [row for row in cursor]
```

or

```
faclist = [row[0] for row in cursor]
```

Look at [arcpy cursor comp](https://gist.github.com/PyBigos/5619723), [SearchCursor example 2](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) and many examples in GIS SE

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to use a with statement or list comprehension so that the cursor doesn't leave a persisting schema lock in the event that your script errors before you delete the cursor object.

Your example answer would work for a limited number of records, but creating a new cursor for each building is unnecessary. Try writing the records to a dictionary then using the dictionary to print results. This will be more efficient if you apply the same solution to a large number of records.

```
# Creat list of buildings    
buildings = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(eadTable, ["SDE_SEWERMAN_BO_BO_UNIQ"])]

# Create dictionary with building name key indexing facility name list
fac_names = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(eadTable, ["BO", "Name"]) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        if row[0] in fac_names.keys():
            fac_names[row[0]].append(row[1])
        else:
            fac_names[row[0]] = [row[1]]

# Print facility names grouped by building number
for b in fac_names.keys():
    print '\n{}'.format(b) 
    for fac in fac_names[b]:
        print '\t{}'.format(fac)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your last loop

```
# Iterate through list of BO#s
for build in buildList:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(eadTable, ["Name"], "{0} = {1}".format("BO", build)) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            facList = []
            facList.append(row[0])
            print(row[0])
    print(build)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by creating individual cursor objects and moving the facList object.

```
# populate buildList with building numbers
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(eadBuild, ["SDE_SEWERMAN_BO_BO_UNIQ"])
for row in cursor:
    buildList.append(row)
    print(row)
del cursor
del row


print(buildList)
print(len(buildList))

# Iterate through list of BO#s
for build in buildList:
    cursor2 = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(eadTable, ["Name"], "BO =" + str(build))
    for row2 in cursor2:
        facList = []
        facList.append(row2)
        print(row2)
    del cursor2
    del row2
    print(build)
```